# Código para mostrar os dados do cliente que fez o login

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Bem a minha questão é a seguinte, ao fazer o login como eu pego os dados da sessão?

Penso que seja fazer um select, mas ao fazê-lo tenho que criar uma sessão? Pois quero buscar os dados somente deste cliente que realizou o login.

Eu já tenho o `login.php` feito, com sessões, etc, mas agora quero criar o `listar_dados.php` (que apenas listará os dados do cliente que fez o login).

Comment: Qual a estrutura da tabela das "pessoas"?

Comment: Nome, data de nascimento, morada, cidade, pais, mail, user,pass

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo as suas perguntas separadamente:

### Como eu pego os dados da sessão?

Utilizando o "php puro", faça o seguinte:

```
$_SESSION['valor']
```

Por exemplo: após o cliente fazer o login, você joga na sessão o id do cliente

```
$_SESSION['cliente']['id'] = $cliente->id;
$_SESSION['cliente']['nome'] = $cliente->nome;
// outros valores aqui
$_SESSION['logado'] = true;
```

### Como utilizo os dados da sessão para buscar algo relacionado a eles?

Após setar os dados na sessão, em uma outra página você deseja buscar algo pelo **id do cliente**, então você faria algo assim:

```
$cliente_id = $_SESSION['cliente']['id'];
```

Agora basta utilizar a variável `$cliente_id` onde você bem desejar (na sua query por exemplo):

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, placa, modelo, marca, valor 
    FROM veiculos 
    WHERE cliente_id < :cliente_id';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->bindParam(':cliente_id', $cliente_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$veiculos = $sth->fetchAll();
```

*Utilizei a tabela veiculos como exemplo, mas no seu caso pode ser outra.*

Qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário.

---

### Links úteis:

- pdo prepare: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php
- bindParam: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer o SELECT baseado no usuário que está salvo na sessão criada no ato do login.

Para ler a sessão, use `$_SESSION['valor']` normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das maneiras de fazer isso seria:

```
/* lembrando que o correto é você ter `user` únicos, ou seja, sem repetir no banco */
$userLogado = $_SESSION[' nome da variavel que você guardou o usuário '];

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'database_name');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Não foi possível se conectar ao servidor [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

/* cria sua query */
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE user = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userLogado);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    /* dentro das aspas vai o nome da sua coluna no banco */
    echo $row['nome'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['data_de_nascimento'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['cidade'] . '<br />';
}
```

Sempre prefira passar parâmetros para a query através do `bind_param` para evitar ataques de [`SQL Injection`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Sugiro você dar uma estudada no assunto, olhe tutorias e video aulas que existem de monte no youtube.

Minha indicação para iniciantes é essa aqui:

### [Sistema de Cadastro e Login de Usuários #1](http://blog.coderweb.com.br/blog/article/sistema-cadastro-login-usuarios-1/)